# hasMany reduced to hasOne in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, relationships, has-one

Basically I have following models in CakePHP:

```
User(id, username)
Photo(id, user_id, path)
```

I have set up following relation: User hasMany Photo.

On one screen, I would like to list users, and show random photo next to each user. I tried setting up following relation:

User hasOne SamplePhoto (where SamplePhoto is just Photo model)

but when user has two photos for instance, he is listed twice on the list.

basically my question is: can you reduce hasMany relation to hasOne, without adding any fields to table schema presented above? I would like to tell cake - find the first record in the Photo table which matches a certain user_id.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [Containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) and then set up something like:

```
$this->User->find(
    'all', 
    array(
        'contains' => array(
            'Photo' => array(
                'order' => 'rand()',
                'limit' => 1
            )
        )
    )
);
```

You should then get something like

```
Array
(
[User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 121
        [username] => tom
    )

[Photo] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 123
                [user_id] => 121
                [path] => Somewhere
            )
    )
```

)

Answer (score 2):

if you do a find like $this->User->read(null,$id), the return will be an array that looks something like:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [username] => tom
        )

    [Photo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [user_id] => 121
                    [path] => Somewhere
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 124
                    [user_id] => 121
                    [path] => SomeOtherPlace
                )
        )            
)
```

From this array you can pick the photo however you like, be it the first:

```
$this->data['Photo'][0]
```

the last:

```
$this->data['Photo'][count($this->data['Photo'])]
```

an explicit record:

```
$this->data['Photo'][3]
```

or by some random means:

```
$this->data['Photo'][$rnd]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't make this more complicated than it needs to be. :)

```
$data = $this->User->Photo->find('first',
        array('conditions' => array('Photo.user_id' => $id)));
```

Gives you a photo in `$data['Photo']` with the user attached in `$data['User']`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd do something like:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' =>
                array('username'=>$this->data['User']['username'],
                      'active'=>true) ));
```

Comment: This will find the first User