# How to avoid duplicate products with Product hasOne Offer?

Tags: sql, cakephp

I have two models Products and Offers. Products hasOne Offer. Models are binded with

```
//Product model:
hasOne
  Offer
     foreignKey => false
     conditions => array(Product.productnumber = Offer.productnumber) // Just normal fields

//Offer model:
belongsTo
    Product
```

There can be many offers with same Offer.productnumber and different Offer.price. What I want to do is find all products so that there is only one offer present with cheapest Offer.price. But now when I trying to do that I get as many duplicate Products as there is Offers with same productnumber. How to avoid this?

I have also seen this: [hasMany reduced to hasOne in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047737/hasmany-reduced-to-hasone-in-cakephp) But no luck with containable.

Is only (easiest) option to get separate arrays and then combine them "manually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product hasMany Offers. Product hasMany LowestOffer with an order clause in the relationship conditions array sorted on price ASC and a limit=>1 clause.

Then do a find with containable and pull the LowestOffer back when you want just the single cheapest offer or pull back Offers when you want them all.

Comment: I guess this could work. Still I ended up fetching two separate arrays and combining them manually. I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Many offers to one product, then you've to use hasMany. product hasMany offers.

That's the way you should model the relationship in your models. I mean, think about it, if you have one book in your store, and it can have only one offer, that makes no sense.

Ok, now, to get all the books that have just 1 offer, i just can think something like this:

```
SELECT p.id FROM products p JOIN offers o ON(p.id=o.product_id) WHERE p.id IN (
   SELECT oo.product_id FROM offers oo GROUP BY oo.product_id WHERE SUM(oo.product_id)=1
)
```

Try to put that in `Model::find()` syntax, or just use the `Model::query()` method.

EDIT:

If you want the offer with the bigger price.

```
SELECT p.id FROM products p JOIN offers o ON(p.id=o.product_id) WHERE p.id IN (
   SELECT oo.product_id FROM offers oo GROUP BY oo.product_id WHERE OO.id = MAX(oo.price)
)
```

Comment: That you for your answer. There is a reason why I don't model that relationship. I populate offers-table from csv and I don't want to look for Product.id for every Offer I save to table. And let me clarify: I want all products and if there is offer with same productnumber I want that also but only the one with the cheapest price. And I prefer not to use $this->Model->query();

Comment: Don't understand Henri. That has no sense. I mean, beyond how you populate your tables, there are relationships that are meant to be. If your product just have one offer, then you're making something wrong. Don't try to model the reallity from technology, do the oposite, model the technology to fit the reallity.

Comment: Well ok then, if Product hasMany Offers my product->find('all') would return all offers with same productnumber. But then I have to build couple foreach loops to unset unnecessary offers after find. Thats also pretty good solution. Thanks. But how I make that array look like after hasOne find? `$products[0][Offer] -> $products[Offer]`

Comment: Updated the anwser. So, to clarify. What do you need?
The product with the bigger offer? Put that and i'll help you.

Comment: Yes all Products with cheapest Offer.price on each.